# Upload small image in a dynamic form?

Tags: javascript, html, image

Using either Javascript or HTML, I have a dynamic form that refreshes/updates each time the user adds data to the table. It even has a 'modify' button and an 'erase' button to delete that particular line. However, one last thing I want to add is a button that would allow the user to upload a picture that would fit in the very last slot of the column. How do I achieve it in such a way that every time the user 'adds' the data (and another row is formed) with that particular image, the next time he wants to add another row he is able to select another image?

```
  window.onload = load;
var id = 1;
var colEmpleados = [];
var colSectores = [{id:1, nombre:"Sector 1"}, 
                   {id:2, nombre:"Sector 2"}, 
                   {id:3, nombre:"Sector 3"}];

function load()
{
    var btnAgregar = document.getElementById("btnAgregar");
    btnAgregar.onclick = agregar;

    var btnConfirmar = document.getElementById("btnConfirmar");
    btnConfirmar.onclick = confirmarModificacion;

    var btnCancelar = document.getElementById("btnCancelar");
    btnCancelar.onclick = cancelar;


    cargarSelectSectores();
    habilitarIngreso();
}

function habilitarIngreso()
{
    var rowA = document.getElementById("rowAgregar");
    rowA.style.display = 'block';

    var rowM = document.getElementById("rowModificar");
    rowM.style.display = 'none';
}

function habilitarModificar()
{
    var rowM = document.getElementById("rowModificar");
    rowM.style.display = 'block';

    var rowA = document.getElementById("rowAgregar");
    rowA.style.display = 'none';
}

function confirmarModificacion()
{
    var idEmpleado = document.getElementById("idEmpleado").value;
    for(var i = 0; i<colEmpleados.length;i++)
    {
        if(colEmpleados[i].idEmpleado == idEmpleado)
        {
            colEmpleados[i].nombre = document.getElementById("txtNombre").value;
            colEmpleados[i].apellido = document.getElementById("txtApellido").value;
            colEmpleados[i].sector = document.getElementById("sltSector").value;
            colEmpleados[i].edad = document.getElementById("txtEdad").value;
            colEmpleados[i].ingreso = document.getElementById("dtpIngreso").value;
        }
    }

    mostrar();
    habilitarIngreso();
    limpiarForm();
}

function cancelar()
{
    habilitarIngreso();
    limpiarForm();
}

function borrar()
{
    var idEmpleado = this.getAttribute("idEmpleado");

    for(var i=0; i<colEmpleados.length; i++)
    {
        if(colEmpleados[i].idEmpleado == idEmpleado)
        {
            colEmpleados.splice(i,1);
        }
    }
    mostrar();  
}

function modificar()
{   
    habilitarModificar();
    var idEmpleado = this.getAttribute("idEmpleado");

    for(var i=0; i<colEmpleados.length; i++)
    {
        if(colEmpleados[i].idEmpleado == idEmpleado)
        {       
            document.getElementById("idEmpleado").value = colEmpleados[i].idEmpleado;
            document.getElementById("txtNombre").value = colEmpleados[i].nombre;
            document.getElementById("txtApellido").value = colEmpleados[i].apellido;
            document.getElementById("sltSector").value = colEmpleados[i].sector;
            document.getElementById("txtEdad").value= colEmpleados[i].edad;
            document.getElementById("dtpIngreso").value= colEmpleados[i].ingreso;
        }
    }
    mostrar();  
}

function cargarSelectSectores()
{
    var selectSectores = document.getElementById("sltSector");
    selectSectores.innerHTML = "<option id='0'>--- Sectores ---</option>";
    for(var i = 0; i<colSectores.length; i++)
    {
        selectSectores.innerHTML +="<option id="+colSectores[i].id+">"+colSectores[i].nombre+"</option>";
    }
    mostrar();  
}

function agregar()
{
    var nombre = document.getElementById("txtNombre").value;
    var apellido = document.getElementById("txtApellido").value;
    var sector = document.getElementById("sltSector").value;
    var edad = document.getElementById("txtEdad").value;
    var fechaIngreso = document.getElementById("dtpIngreso").value;


    var empleado = {};
    empleado.idEmpleado = id;
    empleado.nombre = nombre;
    empleado.apellido = apellido;
    empleado.sector = sector;
    empleado.edad = edad;
    empleado.ingreso = fechaIngreso;

    colEmpleados.push(empleado);
    id++;
    limpiarForm();  
    mostrar();
}

function limpiarForm()
{
    var colInputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

    for(var i = 0; i<colInputs.length; i++)
    {
        if(colInputs[i].type != "button")
        {
            colInputs[i].value = "";    
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("sltSector").value = "0";
}

function mostrar()
{
    var bodyTabla = document.getElementById("datosEmpleados");
    bodyTabla.innerHTML = "";
    for(var i = 0; i<colEmpleados.length; i++)
    {
        var emp = colEmpleados[i];
        bodyTabla.innerHTML +="<tr><td>"+emp.idEmpleado+"</td><td>"+emp.nombre+"</td><td>"+emp.apellido+"</td><td>"+emp.edad+"</td><td>"+emp.sector+"</td><td>"+emp.ingreso+"</td><td><input class='btnBorrar' type='button' value='Borrar' idEmpleado="+emp.idEmpleado+" /></td><td><input class='btnModificar' type='button' value='Modificar' idEmpleado="+emp.idEmpleado+" /></td></tr>";
    }



    var colBotones = document.getElementsByClassName("btnBorrar");
    for(var i = 0; i<colBotones.length; i++)
    {
        colBotones[i].onclick = borrar;
    }

    var colBotonesModificar = document.getElementsByClassName("btnModificar");
    for(var i = 0; i<colBotonesModificar.length; i++)
    {
        colBotonesModificar[i].onclick = modificar;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No source code means no efforts means expect no answer at Stackoverflow.

Comment: Create a dynamic table inside a php while loop, fetch data from your database, update the dynamic table using this data. This is one method you can use.
Please post your code then members here can help you.